# Wireshark Not Filtering by Host/URL

Tags: wireshark

I appear to be unable to filter Wireshark logs by URL. How can I filter my network requests by URL?

Here is what I'm doing (all on the same laptop):

1. `$ sudo wireshark`
2. Add filter `http.host == "www.google.com"` (or `http.host == "google.com"`)
3. Click the blue shark fin to start a new capture
4. `$ curl -I https://www.google.com`
5. No results in the Wireshark UI

Comment: You made an https connection and request, which is encrypted; wireshark can't decrypt it and thus can't analyze it. Try http. (And make sure you select the correct interface before clicking start.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yup that was it. Thank you. If you want to formally answer I'll mark it accepted.